# Find command oddity

Tags: find

I've found using the '*find*' command to search for individual files that some inconsistencies occur. Eg, I wanted to search for a particular file with the word *paper* in its name. If I type `sudo find /mnt  -iname *paper*`
the output is:-

```
/mnt/data/MyPhotos/Wallpapers
```

which is fair enough, except it wasn't what I was looking for. But if I type  `sudo find /mnt  -iname "*paper*"` the output becomes:-

```
/mnt/data/MyMusic/FLV-Music/Joe_Jackson_Sunday_Papers_small.mp4
/mnt/data/MyMusic/FLV-Music/Status_Quo_Paper_Plane_medium.mp4
/mnt/data/MyPhotos/Wallpapers
```

Now I see the file I was searching for (the 2nd one). So why in the first case is only the last file shown as output, whereas in the second case all files including the string *`paper`* in their names are output. Why should the quotes make a difference here.

Answer (score 2):

Without the quotes, the shell is getting to parse the `*` before `find` is, and it's expanding that glob (if it's able to).  With the quotes, the globbing does not occur.

To demonstrate:

```
$ tree
.
├── Wallpapers
└── stuff
    ├── Newspapers
    ├── Wallflowers
    └── Wallpapers

2 directories, 3 files
$ find stuff -iname *paper*
stuff/Wallpapers
$ find stuff -iname '*paper*'
stuff/Wallpapers
stuff/Newspapers
```

Comment: Specifically: there's a file named "Wallpapers" in the current working directory, so the shell expands `sudo find /mnt  -iname *paper*` to `sudo find /mnt  -iname Wallpaper`. If there was no matching file in the current directory, it would've worked. If there were multiple matches, it probably would cause a `find` error.

Comment: '*Wallpapers*' is found in a subfolder, not current working one. It is a folder by the way, not a file. But *find* fails to list files elsewhere with the same string pattern within sub-folders when not using quotes. That suggests to me that I need quotes for the 'find' command to list files as well.

Comment: @PaulBenson I'm not talking about the "Wallpapers" folder the `find` command found, I'm saying there's *another* "Wallpapers" file/folder/whatever in the directory you're in when you run the `find` command. That is, if you ran `ls Wallpapers` before running `find`, it would list something (not give a "No such file or directory" error). Try running `cd /var/empty; sudo find /mnt  -iname *paper*` -- since there isn't anything named "Wallpapers" in /var/empty, this should leave the wildcard unexpanded and hence find all matches.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson The only '*Wallpapers*' result is that folder that was listed in the output for that path recursively (/mnt). There is no **other** file/folder with that name. I don't know why you seem to think there is. `ls Wallpapers` produces nothing as '*Wallpapers*' also happens to be a folder in my Home folder, but it is empty, and I'm searching on a different path anyway.

Comment: @PaulBenson The "Wallpapers" folder in your home folder *is* the other one I'm talking about. I know it's not where you told `find` to search, but that doesn't matter; when the shell sees `*paper*` in the argument list, it looks for matches *in your current working directory* (in this case, your home folder), and replaces it with the match(es).

Comment: I have edited my answer to more clearly illustrate what I suspect is going on.